# Determining direction of equilibrium for metal complex

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, coordination-compounds

> Determine if $K$ is greater or less than $1$.
>
> [image: Cadmium complexes]

At first I thought the equilibrium would favor the right side because this could have to do with ligand binding where the negative charge would probably cause binding to occur tighter than on the left side.

However, I was told that the left side could be favorable due to resonance stabilization. How to properly estimate the value of equilibrium constant?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, equilibrium favors the right side because (Cd) is a soft metal and (S) is soft too, so it binds better to (Cd) than (O), in accordance with the HSAB theory.

Comment: Is there a third choice, where the cadmium is hexacoordinated (to both O and S), or is the question just whether cadmium prefers sulfur or anionic oxygen?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to predict the value for the equilibrium constant, there is the problem that it will be likely to be depend on the environment. I strongly suspect that for the complex dissolved in water the value will be different to if it is dissolved in dichloromethane.

I did a quick search of it in the literature and I can not find the cadmium complex. But there is a closely related compound. It is a copper complex, please see

An electrochiroptical molecular switch: Mechanistic and kinetic studies
Barcena, Homar S.; Liu, Biao; Mirkin, Michael V.; Canary, James W, Inorganic Chemistry, 2005, vol. 44, # 21, p. 7652 - 7660